# How to play a dss audio file in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, audio

I want to play a dss audio file in Asp.net. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In order to play music on the user's machine (as opposed to the Web server), you'll need to use HTML/JavaScript.

To play songs in the ASP.NET, we can use the following tags

```
<embed src="Name of the audio file or vedio file with virtual path"> </embed>

<bgsound src=src="Name of the audio file or vedio file with virtual path"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a web application, playing audio files is the task of the client. This means, the client needs to be capable of recognizing and playing the served sound files.

If you intend to require clients to handle DSS, follow adatapost's answer.

Otherwise, you need to convert DSS to mp3 on the server. Quick web search resulted in various DSS converters which perform (manual) batch conversion.

If you want to convert on-the-fly, you need to find a library which converts DSS to a more common audio file format.